# Have Thunderbird automatically create link from http

Tags: thunderbird

Can Thunderbird automatically make a hyper link when you copy and paste a URL in? For example if you copy and paste (or type) the text in `http://superuser.com` then it automatically becomes a link http://superuser.com Outlook does this and I'm trying to make Thunderbird more like Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird does this normally, it just doesn't show as a hyperlink in the compose window. Unless you specifically create as a link (Ctrl-L in Windows) where you can set alternate text. As long as the recipient has html support and you aren't sending it as plain text, the received email will have the hyperlink.

Send a test message from Thunderbird to yourself to confirm.

Comment: For me, Thunderbird's default delivery format of "auto-detect" isn't doing this, but if I manually set the delivery format to HTML, it acts as this answer describes.